# C++ passing template type as argument gives error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I have the following code, the problem is when I try to pass basic_string type to writeContainer function it gives me error it read the type Cont as **std::_String_val< std::_Simple_types >** so it give me errors like there is no size() method, and does not have end() or begin() methods for for each loop.

the nice thing, when I use vector it works fine, even though they are the same concept !! any help appreciated

```
template< template<typename> class Cont, typename T >
void writeContainer(Stream& stream, const Cont<T>& outValue) {
    stream << (int32_t)outValue.size(); 
    for (auto& v : outValue) {
        stream << v;
    }
}

template<typename T> 
Stream& operator<<(Stream& stream, const basic_string<T>& outValue) {
    writeContainer(stream, outValue); 
    return stream; 
}
```

errors I get, I use VS2013

```
error C2039: 'size' : is not a member of 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>'
see reference to function template instantiation 'void  writeContainer<std::_String_val,std::_Simple_types<char>>(Stream &,const std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>> &)' being compiled
see reference to function template instantiation 'Stream &operator <<<char>(Stream &,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)' being compiled
error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'const std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>'
error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'const std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>'
error C2065: 'v' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: Please _edit_ your post and include the _exact_ error you get.

Comment: what compiler do you use?

Comment: the main issues, is why it get it as std::_String_val< std::_Simple_types > !!

Comment: Probably the template takes more parameters than you think!

Comment: Lightness is referring to [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which takes _three_ template parameters, not one, so `const Cont<T>&` will not deduce what you want.

Comment: std::vector type takes 2 and it works fine ! but here the problem is it replace std::basic_string by std::_String_val< std::_Simple_types >  !!

Comment: could you provide some code -- generalization of your problem that would be able to give the same error on e.g.: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ ?

Comment: What, if any, is the relationship between `writeContainer` and `writeStdContainer`?

Comment: they are the same, I just changed the names before I post here, I edited,

Comment: `std::basic_string` takes three template parameters, and cannot match `Cont`. In this particular implementation, `std::basic_string` happens to be derived from an internal class template named `_String_val`, which, by unlucky coincidence, just happens to take one template parameter. So `Cont` is deduced as `_String_val` - but `_String_val` doesn't have `size()` member. Bottom line: contrary to your assumptions, `Cont` cannot in fact match an arbitrary STL container. Make it a normal template type parameter, rather than a template template parameter. You don't use `T` for anything anyway.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you put that kind of remarks as an answer not as a comment :)

Comment: @CreativeCoder As a side note, why doesn't your template take iterators instead of the whole container?  What if only a subsequence of data needs to be outputted?  If it were designed to take iterators, then the `basic_string` issue becomes moot:  http://ideone.com/jqhrpc

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  yes please post it as an answer, I did what you said and its works.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, I like what you said, I will use your way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a template template parameter, the argument must be a class template with the exact same number of parameters - counting parameters that have defaults. Thus, even though `std::vector` can be instantiated with one argument, it's a two-parameter template (the second parameter has a default), and cannot be an argument for `Cont`. Similarly, `std::basic_string` is a three-parameter template.

What happens in your example is this. In this particular implementation, `std::basic_string` is derived from an internal class called `_String_val` which, by unlucky coincidence, just happens to be a one-parameter template. So `Cont` is deduced to be `_String_val`, but then the instantiation fails as `_String_val` does not have a method named `size` (that method is implemented by `basic_string` itself).

Despite your claim to the contrary, I get a [similar error](http://rextester.com/VNCWB29359) when using `std::vector` in place of `std::basic_string` - for the exact same reason.

Now, there's no reason to make `Cont` a template template parameter (and a good reason not to - it won't work). Make it a plain type parameter, or else have the function take a pair of iterators. Something along these lines:

```
template<typename Cont>
void writeContainer(Stream& stream, const Cont& outValue);

// or

template<typename Iter>
void writeRange(Stream& stream, Iter first, Iter last);
```